# Why is the rest of my JS code not letting my JQuery run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

apologies for the basic question but I'm just starting to learn JS. I'm trying to build a blackjack game, and I started off in my .js file by creating a constructor function (for the cards) and then I defined one of the methods in that function. Here is the code in my .js file (I've not shown what's inside the actual cardToString function as it's about 70 lines long):
EDIT: Some people have asked I include the entire code, so here it is:

```
 function Card(rank, suit) {
this.rank = rank;
this.suit = suit;
this.toString = cardToString;
this.createNode = cardCreateNode;
}
function cardToString() {
var rank;
var suit;
switch (this.rank) {
    case "A" :
        rank = "Ace";
        break;
    case "2" :
        rank = "Two";
        break;
    case "3" :
        rank = "Three";
        break;
    case "4" :
        rank = "Four";
        break;
    case "5" :
        rank = "Five";
        break;
    case "6" :
        rank = "Six";
        break;
    case "7" :
        rank = "Seven";
        break;
    case "8" :
        rank = "Eight";
        break;
    case "9" :
        rank = "Nine";
        break;
    case "10" :
        rank = "Ten";
        break;
    case "J" :
        rank = "Jack";
        break;
    case "Q" :
        rank = "Queen";
        break;
    case "K" :
        rank = "King";
        break;
    default :
        rank = null;
        break;
    }
switch (this.suit) {
    case "C" :
        suit = "Clubs";
        break;
    case "D" :
        suit = "Diamonds";
        break;
    case "H" :
        suit = "Hearts";
        break;
    case "S" :
        suit = "Spades";
        break;
    default :
        suit = nill;
        break;
    }

if (rank == null || suit == null)
    return "";
else
    return rank + " of " suit;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#deal").click(function() {
    $("#hit").fadeOut('slow');
});

});
```

I'm completely confused, because when I put this into the .js file the jQuery doesn't work, however when I comment out everything but the jQuery it works fine. I'm sure it's something basic that I'm just not aware of, but I've searched for a while and can't find an answer. Basically, I have no idea why my first few bits of JS stop the jQuery from working.

EDIT: Someone asked me if I checked the console for errors, and sure enough I do get one:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Next to this it said "jsjquery.js:4" and I think 4 refers to the line of code which was an empty line right at the beginning (I have some comments on the first few lines, then left a line before I starting coding). I removed empty line, now it says the error is on line 80, which is this piece of code:

```
 return rank + " of " suit;
```

This error goes away when I comment out everything but the jQuery.
This might make everything clear to you guys, but I'm still lost!

Thanks.

EDIT: Ok final edit I promise, haha. For anyone who might come across this question looking for an answer: I made a couple of syntax mistakes, but the real problem was that I didn't define the method cardCreateNode. I didn't realise that not doing so would cause everything else to not run. Thank you to everyone who responded!

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Did you post all your code? `cardCreateNode` isn't defined anywhere in what you posted.

Comment: See [How to debug javascript](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+debug+javascript). There are many very good blogs/articles/questions on how to get started and learning how to debug.

Comment: share what error ur getting...

Comment: Did you put the `<script>` element to add jQuery before your JS?

Comment: Um... I think it's best that you post all 70 lines of code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co).

Comment: No, the relevant code should be posted **here**.

Comment: @ Umakant Mane I'm not getting an error message, but when I click the button the function doesn't run. When I comment out everything but the JSQuery, then when the button is clicked, the other button fades out.

Comment: @Richard Can you explain what you mean? In my html file just before the closing </body> tag, I have a script tag for the jQuery file which I downloaded uncompressed, and then directly after that I include a script tag for this specific .js file.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. If you are getting no errors I suggest adding a `debugger` statement and opening with your browser's dev tools open. NB. just noticed you are getting an error: that will have a line number to tell you were the JS engine found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a different error based on the update of your post I'll answer your latest issue being that you receive an error on this line:

```
return rank + " of " suit;
```

You are missing the concatenation on the other side of " of " so it should look like this:

```
return rank + " of " + suit;
```

Also in your switch statement you have this line:

```
default :
    suit = nill;
    break;
```

I think here you mean to set the value to null not nill which would look like this:

```
default :
    suit = null;
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing that pesky " + " sign! However now I'm getting the following:

Comment: Ok this should be in my above comment but I pressed enter by mistake... The error message I get now is "Uncaught ReferenceError: cardCreateNode is not defined". Am I not defining it when I say this.createNode = cardCreateNode within the function?

Comment: You haven't included the code for the cardCreateNode function in your original post so I can't see what that looks like. Perhaps update your original question to include this? Is it in a separate file? And if so is it loaded before the file that contains the code in your original quesiton?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I haven't defined that method yet, is this the problem? If I assign a method to an object do I need to define it even if I'm not using it? I just assumed it wouldn't do anything unless I actually used it, which is why I was confused that my jQuery wasn't even working as it has nothing to do with the objects... If so I'll define all of the methods as basic functions and then see if that works.

Comment: As you've already worked out yes it needed to be defined. No problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
default :
        suit = nill;
        break;
```

unexpected identifier is syntax error. Obviously you mean null here, not nill.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for pointing it out! But I'm still getting the same error message for line 80...